# Unity: Intense lag caused (possibly) by cine machine or too many colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using [Cinemachine](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/cinemachine-79898) asset in my Unity project and is working fine without any lag. However, the places in my Scene which has a lot of ladders, are facing intense lag, making the game unplayable. Such a scene is shown below.
[image]

Reasons that I can think of the lag is too many collisions happening or the cinemachine(may be). Two images below show the physics shape of the ladder sprite. 
[image]
[image]

My camera is set-up inside an empty gameobject called "Cameras" as shown below. The state driven camera utilizes the player animator which is shown in the second screenshot. I am afraid that I can not provide a minimal reproducible example in this case. Could someone help me by pointing in the right direction to fix the lag?
[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT:** Unity profile also suggests that Physics usage is consuming too much CPU with `CinemachineBrain.AfterPhysics()` and `Physics2D.FindNewContacts` being the major culprit:
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2:** The ladder is created using a tilemap component as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try simplifying the collider boxes for the ladder to a single box collider shape?

Comment: Yes, I removed all the inner colliders and it worked. Thanks.